# How to set top | bottom | left | right for a div based on props in StyledComponent?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm creating a `React Toast` component with StyledComponent and I want to empower the developers who will use it to set these positions:

```
1. TopRight
2. TopLeft
3. BottomRight
4. BottomLeft
```

The developers set the position through the prop `position` in the `Toast` component:

```js
<Toast position={/**What should I do here */} 
       withBorder
       title={'Happy New Year'}
       message={'I resolve to stop wasting my resolutions on myself and use them to repay you for the warmth you’ve shown me. Happy New Year!'} />
```

I'm using Styled Components ( css ) to set the position but I don't know the **right logic**.

The `Container` is the layout for the Toast component.

```css
    const Container = styled.div`
       position: absolute;
       top: 0; /**how to set the bottom property based on React prop**/
       bottom: 0; /** how to set the right property based on React prop**/
       right: 0; /** how to set the right property based on React prop**/
       left: 0; /**how to set the bottom property based on React prop**/
       animation: ${fadeIn} 2s;
       display: block;
       min-width: 20%;
       width: 20%;
       margin: 10px;
       border: solid;
       border-width: ${({ withBorder }) => {
          return withBorder ? '0.1px' : 0;
       }};
       border-color: #999;
       border-radius: 4px;
       box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
       padding: 8px;
    `;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `switch` case within your `StyledComponent` and assign coordinates for your `top`, `bottom`, `left`,`right` according to prop.
Here, I've renamed the prop to `toastPosition` to avoid confusion.
Like:

```
const Container = styled.div`
       position: absolute;
       top: ${({ toastPosition }) => {
    switch (toastPosition) {
      case "TopRight":
        return 0;
      case "TopLeft":
        return 0;
      default:
        return "initial";
    }
  }};

  bottom: ${({ toastPosition }) => {
    switch (toastPosition) {
      case "BottomRight":
        return 0;
      case "BottomLeft":
        return 0;
      default:
        return "initial";
    }
  }};

  left: ${({ toastPosition }) => {
    switch (toastPosition) {
      case "TopLeft":
        return 0;
      case "BottomLeft":
        return 0;
      default:
        return "initial";
    }
  }};

  right: ${({ toastPosition }) => {
    switch (toastPosition) {
      case "BottomRight":
        return 0;
      case "TopRight":
        return 0;
      default:
        return "initial";
    }
  }};
       animation: ${fadeIn} 2s;
       display: block;
       min-width: 20%;
       width: 20%;
       margin: 10px;
       border: solid;
       border-width: ${({ withBorder }) => {
          return withBorder ? '0.1px' : 0;
       }};
       border-color: #999;
       border-radius: 4px;
       box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
       padding: 8px;
    `;
```

Added a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-forked-ukqzb?file=/index.js) for the same

Answer (score 0):

Because there's not `Enums` in Javascript, I've solved the issue by passing an `Object` called `position` which contains four properties which they are the desired positions :

```js
const position = {
   TOP_LEFT: 'TOPLEFT',
   TOP_RIGHT: 'TOPRIGHT',
   BOTTOM_LEFT: 'BOTTOMLEFT',
   BOTTOM_RIGHT: 'BOTTOMRIGHT',
};
```

Then I send the desired position through a prop called `position`:

```js
  <Toast position={position.TOP_RIGHT} withBorder title={'Happy New Year'} message={'I resolve to stop wasting my resolutions on myself and use them to repay you for the warmth you’ve shown me. Happy New Year!'} />
```

The Container ( the layout for the Toast ) adapts this prop to set the desired position:

```js
const Container = styled.div`
   position: absolute;
   top: ${({ position }) => {
      if (position === 'TOPRIGHT' || position === 'TOPLEFT') return 0;
   }};
   bottom: ${({ position }) => {
      if (position === 'BOTTOMRIGHT' || position === 'BOTTOMLEFT') return 0;
   }};
   right: ${({ position }) => {
      if (position === 'TOPRIGHT' || position === 'BOTTOMRIGHT') return 0;
   }};
   left: ${({ position }) => {
      if (position === 'TOPLEFT' || position === 'BOTTOMLEFT') return 0;
   }};
   animation: ${fadeIn} 2s;
   display: block;
   min-width: 20%;
   width: 20%;
   margin: 10px;
   border: solid;
   border-width: ${({ withBorder }) => {
      return withBorder ? '0.1px' : 0;
   }};
   border-color: #999;
   border-radius: 4px;
   box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   padding: 8px;
`;
```